NASM DWARF Debugging Issue with gdb
I'm encountering an issue while debugging NASM assembly code using gdb. The error message I receive is:
(gdb) print num 
'num' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type 
(gdb) print &num 
$1 = (<data variable, no debug info> *) 0x402000 <num>

However, when I cast the variable, I get the correct value:
(gdb) print (short)num 
$2 = 5

Here are the details of my setup:
NASM Version: 2.16.01
GNU ld Version: 2.42
GNU gdb Version: 15.0.50.20240403-0ubuntu1
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
code snippet
section .data
    num: dd 5  ; Declare a double word (32-bit) variable

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Move the value 123 into the EAX register
    mov eax, 123
    ; Store the value of EAX into the memory location labeled 'num'
    mov [num], eax

    ; Exit the program
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

I've followed these steps to generate and link DWARF debugging information:
Assembling with DWARF debugging information:
nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf -g -o main.o main.asm
ld -m elf_x86_64 -g -o main

Despite this, gdb still cannot determine the type of the variable num. Here is the relevant section of the DWARF debug information from objdump:
main.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of the .debug_info section:

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0:
   Length:        0x5b (32-bit)
   Version:       3
   Abbrev Offset: 0
   Pointer Size:  8
 <0><b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <c>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0
    <14>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x18
    <1c>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0
    <20>   DW_AT_name        : main.asm
    <29>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : /home/userName/assembly/
    <3e>   DW_AT_producer    : NASM 2.16.01
    <4b>   DW_AT_language    : 32769    (MIPS assembler)
 <1><4d>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <4e>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0
    <56>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0 (location list)
 <1><5a>: Abbrev Number: 0


Has anyone else encountered this issue? Are there any additional steps or configurations that I might be missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

The discussion here may be relevant: GDB shows error message when trying to print a variable in an Assembly program
